I wonder if it is possible to store the key pair separately and use it externally instead of storing it in the wallet of the local node
I am a Korean wallet blockchain developer!
While developing EOS, something came up that I was curious about, so I decided to post this.
I understand that in the case of EOS, a wallet is registered on a local node and a private key (key pair) is registered in the registered wallet.
I understand that you have to register like this for signing and broadcasting to take place.
I wonder if it is possible to store the key pair separately and use it externally instead of storing it in the wallet of the local node.
Is it possible to sign and send without registering a key pair in the wallet?
thank you
